# too many redirections in my server

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Just now im pointing to squarespace to see my webpage, but since now I want to manage my own webpage from my server but when I change the DNS to redirect to my site, chrome and safari said too many redirections.

this is my htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule> 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^minutos\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.minutos\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.minutos\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

But I don't know how to solve this mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^minutos\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.minutos\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.minutos\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

The above is redirecting in an infinite loop, change to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^minutos\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.minutos\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last 301 rule is running for `www` and non-www and redirecting to www hence causing a redirect loop.

Have it this way:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^minutos\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```